# QLibrary cannot resolve a function in shared library

Tags: c++, qt5, qlibrary

I'm trying to include functions dynamically from shared library created with Qt. I use the QLibrary to do it. But I have the following problem: when I try to call the QLibrary::resolve() method, it always returns 0.

This is header file **qtarithmetic.h** of my shared library:

```
#ifndef QTARITHMETIC_H
#define QTARITHMETIC_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(QTARITHMETIC_LIBRARY)
#  define QTARITHMETICSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define QTARITHMETICSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class QTARITHMETICSHARED_EXPORT Qtarithmetic
{

public:
    Qtarithmetic();
    int add(int, int);
    int sub(int, int);
};

#endif // QTARITHMETIC_H
```

This is cpp file **qtarithmetic.cpp** of my shared library:

```
#include "qtarithmetic.h"

Qtarithmetic::Qtarithmetic() {}

extern "C" QTARITHMETICSHARED_EXPORT int Qtarithmetic::add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

extern "C" QTARITHMETICSHARED_EXPORT int Qtarithmetic::sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

This is **.pro** file of test project which use my library:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = qt-arithmetic-use
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

This is **.cpp** file of this test project:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLibrary>

int main() {
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    int a = 0, b = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
    a = 3; b = 4;

    QLibrary library("/home/danil/build-qt-arithmetic-Desktop-Debug/libqt-arithmetic.so");
    if (!library.load())
        out << library.errorString() << endl;
    if (library.load())
        out << "library loaded" << endl;

    typedef int (*MyPrototype)(int, int);

    MyPrototype myFunction = (MyPrototype)library.resolve("add");
    if (myFunction)
        r1 = myFunction(a,b);
    else
        out << library.errorString() << endl;

    MyPrototype myFunction2 = (MyPrototype)library.resolve("sub");
    if (myFunction2)
        r2 = myFunction2(a,b);
    else
        out << library.errorString() << endl;

    out << r1 << " " << r2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**library.errorString()** contains the following information:

```
Cannot resolve symbol "add" in /home/danil/build-qt-arithmetic-Desktop-Debug/libqt-arithmetic.so: (/home/danil/build-qt-arithmetic-Desktop-Debug/libqt-arithmetic.so: undefined symbol: add)
Cannot resolve symbol "sub" in /home/danil/build-qt-arithmetic-Desktop-Debug/libqt-arithmetic.so: (/home/danil/build-qt-arithmetic-Desktop-Debug/libqt-arithmetic.so: undefined symbol: sub)
```

Comment: You are defining class methods in your library, but trying to resolve free functions (i.e. `Qtarithmetic::add` is not `add`). Also, the prototype in your client code doesn't match the library (non-static methods have a `this` pointer). If you don't actually need these functions to be in a class, get rid of the class. See the [example in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlibrary.html#resolve).

Comment: Thank you! I removed class definition `Qtarithmetic` in file qtarithmetic.cpp, and now my program is works fine.